# Why are certain stars not moving in this timelapse video?

Tags: stars, astrophotography

In this video, certain stars are not moving in the bottom left & top right corners. I thought only the pole star didn't move.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QC8iQqtG0hg&ab_channel=PanamaCityNewsHerald

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like "hot pixels" in the image sensor. They look sharper than the star images: they are unaffected by the atmosphere and the lens point-spread function.

No sensor is perfect. Much of astronomical image processing involves dealing with the artifacts introduced into images by sensor imperfections. These images have apparently not been "scrubbed" to remove hot pixels.

Comment: Hi, I think that's it! Thanks for the answer. I found a related question thread on the photography StackExchange of someone having the same issue. https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/25909/109867